# C# upload XLS file into FTP

Tags: c#

I use following code to upload *.xls file into FTP. It works fine for uploading, but the content of *.xls file in FTP all mess up

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"ftp://www.xxxxxx.com" + fileName);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;


request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(filePath);

byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

response.Close();
```

Any one know how to fix this problem???????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insted of this:

```
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(filePath);
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();
```

Try to use this:

```
byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
```

It might be encoding\decoding problem.